# Text overlap in hamburger menu for wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor, hamburger-menu

I am managing a wordpress website which was developed by someone else. The website is using a variant of *Hello Elementor Child* theme.

The problem I am facing is that the text of menu items is overlapping when the hamburger menu is opened. I am trying to adjust (reduce) the font size of the main menu items, but I have't had any success so far. The sub-items work fine.

Also, this problem only occurs for the desktop version of the site and works well for the mobile and the tablet versions.

I am not really a web developer and my knowledge of CSS is almost zero. So, any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance for your help!

Below is a screenshot of the menu.

[Screenshot of the current hamburger menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEUaZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have to increase the CSS line-height property. I think it will be fixed with that.